# must clear insert buffer-string?

Tags: insert

This code

```
(defun insert-dateutc.* ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (with-temp-buffer
            (call-process "date" nil t nil "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            (buffer-substring-no-properties 1 (line-end-position 0)))))

(defun insert-random-uuid.* ()
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (call-process "uuidgen" nil t nil)
    (buffer-substring-no-properties 1 (line-end-position 0))))
```

which works stand-alone, but when stuck into this code

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (format "'(start-symbol :id %s
               :graph 
               :ts %s
               :0.0 
               :1.0 
               )" (insert-random-uuid.*) (insert-dateutc.*))))
```

produces this:

```
2015-11-19T16:07:38'(start-symbol :id 9c5a8a91-325a-44d1-8535-03afc10f405a
               :graph 
               :ts nil
               :0.0 
               :1.0 
               )nil
```

That is, it's sticking the formatted date outside the `format` output. I can only assume that I'm going to the `buffer-substring-no-properties` too many times, or it needs to be reset or something. An earlier version that simply did this

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (format "'(start-symbol :id %s
               :graph 
               :ts %s
               :0.0 
               :1.0 
               )" (insert-random-uuid.*) (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))))
```

played well with `insert-random-uuid.*`

See:

```
'(start-symbol :id 2bfebed2-82c3-4ccb-b9f3-84b82a421e06
               :graph 
               :ts 2015-11-19T16:21:39
               :0.0 
               :1.0 
               )nil
```

Not sure what the problem is. . . .

Comment: Did you forget to remove the call to `insert` from `insert-dateutc.*`? (And maybe remove "insert" from both function names?)

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to solve it. Calling `insert` too many times is bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function inserts text into a buffer, it should be called `insert-something` and its return value should *not* be passed to `format` and friends.

I.e., rename `insert-random-uuid.*` to `get-random-uuid.*` and `insert-dateutc.*` to `get-dateutc.*` and remove the `insert` call from the latter.